# webpack: custom style is missing after production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I've updated my webpack file. Now it's won't apply my custom style to the main style bundle. No errors, classes with custom style just missing in bundle. 
When I'm running build with `development` mode - everything is ok and my styles are exist in the bundle. Such happens only with `production` build.

I tried `extract-text-webpack-plugin` instead `mini-css-extract-plugin` but result is same - in prod build my styles are missing.

I'll be very apriciated for any kind of help.

Here is files:

*webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const lessToJs = require('less-vars-to-js');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

const publicPath = 'public';
const themeVariables = lessToJs(
  fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './assets/style/ant-theme-vars.less'), 'utf8'),
);

module.exports = (env, options) => {
  const mode = env ? env.mode : options.mode;
  return {
    entry: './assets/app.jsx',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, publicPath),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.less$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
            },
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: [
                  autoprefixer({
                    browsers: 'last 2 version',
                  }),
                ],
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'less-loader',
              options: {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
                modifyVars: themeVariables,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          exclude: [/node_modules/],
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
            },
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: [
                  autoprefixer({
                    browsers: 'last 2 version',
                  }),
                ],
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: [/node_modules/],
          loaders: ['babel-loader'],
          resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
          exclude: [/node_modules/],
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: 'img/[name].[ext',
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
              options: {
                mozjpeg: {
                  progressive: true,
                  quality: 70,
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          exclude: [/node_modules/],
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(publicPath, {}),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'bundle.css',
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './assets/www/index.html',
      }),
    ],
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
          cache: true,
          parallel: true,
          uglifyOptions: {
            compress: true,
            mangle: true,
            warnings: false,
            drop_console: true,
            unsafe: true,
          },
          sourceMap: true,
        }),
      ],
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname),
      compress: true,
      port: 9000,
      publicPath: '/',
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    devtool: mode === 'development' ? 'cheap-inline-module-source-map' : '',
  };
};
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "react-templates",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bundle.js",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --mode production",
    "build-dev": "webpack -p --progress --mode development",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode production --open",
    "eslint": "eslint . --ext .js --ext .jsx",
    "stylelint": "stylelint assets/scss",
    "deploy-current-branch-dev": "npm run build-dev && firebase deploy",
    "deploy-dev": "git checkout -- . && git clean -fd && git checkout develop && git remote update && git pull  && npm run build-dev && firebase deploy"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "3.8.2",
    "autoprefixer": "9.0.1",
    "brace": "0.11.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.19",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "fast-async": "^6.3.8",
    "file-system": "2.2.2",
    "firebase": "5.3.0",
    "history": "4.7.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "less-vars-to-js": "1.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.3",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-ace": "6.1.4",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-favicon": "0.0.14",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "react-router": "4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.5",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.9.1",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.9.1",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "husky": "1.0.0-rc.13",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.3.1",
    "less": "3.8.1",
    "less-loader": "4.1.0",
    "node-sass": "4.9.2",
    "postcss-loader": "2.1.6",
    "sass-loader": "7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "0.21.0",
    "stylelint": "9.4.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "2.1.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run eslint && npm run stylelint"
    }
  }
}
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
"presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        [
            "import",
            {
                "libraryName": "antd",
                "style": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The probplem is `sideEffects: false` in my `package.json` file.

I found an [issue on Github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6741) and there are some issues related to it.

Main reason I did it - I wanted to make a tree shank in my development mode. It worked as I expected but in production mode all my custom styles are missing. To solve this problem I just removed `sideEffects: false`. So I lost tree shank in dev mode (think it's not good solution to make it in development mode but however).

Comment: Oh my god, I was looking for this issue for 4 hours, this was the fix!! (I've added "*.css" and "*.scss" as an array to my package.json)

Comment: Would you mind sharing where this code goes inside of package.json. Sorry I see you're saying delete it. I don't have it in there, but still missing certain parts of certain css files when running production. Seems when minifying it removes rules?!

Comment: Hi, @warmwhisky . Looks like you have another case than described in my question. There are a lot of dependencies that may affect on builds with different environment.

Comment: @hofshteyn Yes. I found that I was missing styles that were only in the page after JavaScript dynamically created said elements. I found ways around ignoring this in purgeCss with ignore rules directly in my css files using `/* purgecss ignore */` or `/* purgecss start ignore */` & `/* purgecss end ignore */`